# java.io.IOException HttpURLConnection.getInputStream

Tags: java, url, xml-parsing

Description in Brief guys:

i have a url hold content of an xml file.
i want to parse this file to i use this code below:

```
private String GetFileUrl() {
    return "https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/My%20Projects/Xml%20Files/Vk%20Iu%20Quilling/KeyList.xml?w=AAD6Cf_YdXRg5tyY4cquyiXBZ8XuQUsIbsMGVoIfkgPcpg";
}

private NodeList SetUpXmlParserUrl() {
    try {
        URL xmlFile = new URL(fileUrl);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream = xmlFile.openStream();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream);

        //Get Node need to be parse.
        NodeList productNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");
        return productNodeList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

When this code run i get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/My%20Projects/Xml%20Files/Vk%20Iu%20Quilling/KeyList.xml?w=AAD6Cf_YdXRg5tyY4cquyiXBZ8XuQUsIbsMGVoIfkgPcpg
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

Can anyone help please..

Comment: HTTP 403: Forbidden. You don't have access to this URL.

Comment: You need to authenticate with dropbox somehow.. Check if they provide a (programaticaly) way to do this

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to be loged in to access the file, you did that on your browser but your application does not have the authorization to do so.

HTTP 403 means the URL is Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

normally you should use dropbox api, like this example:

```
public class DropboxTest {

private static final String APP_KEY = "APP KEY";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "SECRET KEY";
private static final AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;
private static DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession> mDBApi;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    WebAuthSession session = new WebAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
    WebAuthInfo authInfo = session.getAuthInfo();

    RequestTokenPair pair = authInfo.requestTokenPair;
    String url = authInfo.url;

    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(url).toURI());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press ok to continue once you have authenticated.");
    session.retrieveWebAccessToken(pair);

    AccessTokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
    System.out.println("Use this token pair in future so you don't have to re-authenticate each time:");
    System.out.println("Key token: " + tokens.key);
    System.out.println("Secret token: " + tokens.secret);

    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession>(session);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Uploading file...");
    String fileContents = "Hello World!";
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContents.getBytes());
    Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/testing.txt", inputStream, fileContents.length(), null, null);
    System.out.println("Done. \nRevision of file: " + newEntry.rev);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The url that u have given is not permitted with java access. Check your connection and set proxy host/port into yourjava connection.

Or u can read it as HttpRequest's response, that can be doable also